# Negative index error in R

Tags: r, algorithm

**The following commands work:**

```
ge$OneD[3:503] <- (((ge$Adj.Close[2:(502)] - ge$Adj.Close[1:(501)])/ ge$Adj.Close[(1:501)] ) * 100)
ge$FiveD[7:503] <- (((ge$Adj.Close[6:502] - ge$Adj.Close[1:(497)])/ ge$Adj.Close[1:(497)]) * 100)
```

**The following commands don't work:**

```
n = nrows(ge
```

*n is initialized to 503*

```
ge$OneD[3:n] <- (((ge$Adj.Close[2:n-1] - ge$Adj.Close[1:n-2])/ ge$Adj.Close[1:n-2] ) * 100)
ge$five[7:n] <- (((ge$Adj.Close[6:n-1] - ge$Adj.Close[1:n-6])/ ge$Adj.Close[1:n-6]) * 100)
```

Throws error:

```
Error in ge$Adj.Close[1:n - 2] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Can we not use variables as indices in this way?

Comment: Compare the following in your console: `1:5 - 2` versus `1:(5-2)`. The colon operator has higher precedence.

Comment: Thank you so much @joran
That fixed my mistake